# WSO 2 odata service Oracle database problem: Can't get type of a primary key with auto-increment

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I've been using odata service for CRUD with Oracle database. Thing still went well with Update, Read, and Delete, but when I try to create a record, thing doesn't go well.

```html
[2023-11-24 09:19:42,880] ERROR {ODataAdapter} - Error occurred. :Cannot invoke "org.apache.olingo.commons.api.data.Property.getType()" because the return value of "org.apache.olingo.commons.api.data.Entity.getProperty(String)" is null java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.olingo.commons.api.data.Property.getType()" because the return value of "org.apache.olingo.commons.api.data.Entity.getProperty(String)" is null
2023-11-24 16:19:42     at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.odata.ODataUtils.buildLocation(ODataUtils.java:91)
2023-11-24 16:19:42     at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.odata.ODataAdapter.createEntity(ODataAdapter.java:594)
2023-11-24 16:19:42     at org.apache.olingo.server.core.requests.DataRequest$EntityRequest.execute(DataRequest.java:370)
2023-11-24 16:19:42     at org.apache.olingo.server.core.requests.DataRequest.execute(DataRequest.java:247)
2023-11-24 16:19:42     at org.apache.olingo.server.core.ServiceDispatcher.internalExecute(ServiceDispatcher.java:166)
2023-11-24 16:19:42     at org.apache.olingo.server.core.ServiceDispatcher.execute(ServiceDispatcher.java:97)
2023-11-24 16:19:42     at org.apache.olingo.server.core.OData4HttpHandler.process(OData4HttpHandler.java:67)
2023-11-24 16:19:42     at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.odata.ODataServiceHandler.process(ODataServiceHandler.java:80)
2023-11-24 16:19:42     at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.odata.endpoint.ODataEndpoint.lambda$process$0(ODataEndpoint.java:104)
2023-11-24 16:19:42     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

The record was inserted successfully into the database, but a 500 Response still appear.
Finally, I find out that wso 2 odata service can't detect type of my primary key (ID), which is set to be auto-increment (Type number, and I was using sequence), and was absent in my payload. When I put in a value (Like ID:20), the create method returned a success http 201 response.

Oracle driver: ojdbc11.jar.
Driver type: thin.
MI version: 4.2.0

Can I find a way to bypass this?